# Error in Prefect flow when passing large dataframe as argument

Tags: python, h2, orchestration, prefect

I am trying to implement orchestration of a ml-pipeline with Prefect. The entire pipeline works fine when passing a small enough batch of raw data. But once I pass a larger batch, some of the flows suddenly cannot be created.

The first flows in the pipeline still works fine, which perform some data cleaning and feature generation. But once I have a cleaned dataframe of about 10 000 rows and one column containing text data and try to processes it in a flow that makes predictions based on a pretrained model, I get one of the following errors:

1.

```
Exception has occurred: ReadTimeout 

The operation did not complete (read) (_ssl.c:2633)ssl.SSLWantReadError: The operation did not complete (read) (_ssl.c:2633)  

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  

asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:  

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  

TimeoutError:  

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  httpcore.ReadTimeout:  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:  File "C:\Users\EmilEne\OneDrive - Brand Delta\Documents\GitHub\airflow_ds_test\ds_nomad\model_age\age_prediction.py", line 108, in <module> test = new_predictions(df, m['model'], column='cleaned_message', language='italian', market='italy') httpx.ReadTimeout:
```

Or 2.

```
Exception has occurred: LocalProtocolError
1 

h2.exceptions.StreamClosedError: 1  

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  

httpcore.LocalProtocolError: 1  

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:  

File "C:\Users\EmilEne\OneDrive - Brand Delta\Documents\GitHub\airflow_ds_test\ds_nomad\model_age\age_prediction.py", line 105, in <module> test = new_predictions(df, m['model'], column='cleaned_message', language='italian', market='italy') httpx.LocalProtocolError: 1
```

I tried using the debugger in vs code to see where in the function of the flow breaks but it never enters the function, it seems the flow is never even created. I tried replacing the whole function of the flow to just a print statement like this:

```
from prefect import task, flow
import pandas as pd

@flow()
def predictions(df):
   print(df.info())

df_test = pd.read_parquet(".../path")
test = predicitons(df_test)
```

But it still doesn't create the flow and gives me the same error, the df_test is also one column and 7000 rows of cleaned text data.

I really don't understand the errors, I have no knowledge SSL or h2. Anybody that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

`df_test = pd.read_parquet(".../path")` isn't a valid relative file path.

If you want to go up two levels you would do `df_test = pd.read_parquet("../../path")`